# Execute graphics operations when source of binding changes

Tags: c#, mvvm, binding, mvvmcross

I am currently developing a .Net applications based on the MVVM architectural pattern and using the MvvmCross framework.

I would like to execute some graphics operations so in the code behind of my View when a property of the ViewModel binded has been modified.

The Binding works well, ie the UI is well updated but I would like to do something else when the property is changed.

How can I do such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view's code behind:

```
 public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var vm = DataContext as MainViewModel;
        vm.PropertyChanged += vm_PropertyChanged;
    }

    void vm_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.PropertyName == "MyProperty")
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
```